# BackboneJS save sending GET instead of PUT

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

My BackboneJS models now send a `GET` instead of `PUT` when I call the `model.save()` method.
I have a Django back-end with django-tastypie for the REST api.

For example, I have a user model that I try to update like this:

```
var me = new UserModel({
    id: this.user.id
});
me.fetch({
    success: function (t) {
        console.log(t);
        t.set({
            'premium': true
        });
        t.save({
            success: function () {
                alert('success')
            },
            error: function (m, e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/100003258103084/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

in the line where I have `t.save()`

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Alright, the message that it shows int he line `console.log(e)` is as follow:

```
"{"error_message": "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 192, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 406, in dispatch_detail\n    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 427, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1131, in put_detail\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_update(bundle, request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1827, in obj_update\n    m2m_bundle = self.hydrate_m2m(bundle)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 743, in hydrate_m2m\n    bundle.data[field_name] = field_object.hydrate_m2m(bundle)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 742, in hydrate_m2m\n    m2m_hydrated.append(self.build_related_resource(value, **kwargs))\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 593, in build_related_resource\n    return self.resource_from_data(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 548, in resource_from_data\n    return fk_resource.obj_update(fk_bundle, **data)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1814, in obj_update\n    bundle.obj = self.obj_get(request, **lookup_kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1752, in obj_get\n    base_object_list = self.get_object_list(request).filter(**kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 621, in filter\n    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 639, in _filter_or_exclude\n    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py\", line 1250, in add_q\n    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py\", line 1185, in add_filter\n    connector)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py\", line 69, in add\n    value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py\", line 320, in prepare\n    return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 137, in get_prep_lookup\n    return self._pk_trace(value, 'get_prep_lookup', lookup_type)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 210, in _pk_trace\n    v = getattr(field, prep_func)(lookup_type, v, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py\", line 310, in get_prep_lookup\n    return self.get_prep_value(value)\n\n  File \"/home/mohamed/code/skempi/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py\", line 537, in get_prep_value\n    return int(value)\n\nTypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'\n"}"
```

Does this mean that the problem is in Django-Tastypie and not with BackbonejS? Still this `GET` is the issue i guess!

Comment: Looks like `me.fetch` could be triggering this

Comment: Can you elaborate further please?

Comment: Just to be clear: is the original `GET` from `me.fetch` succeeding?

Comment: @JayC: Yes I can see the model's details in the line `console.log(t)`

Answer (score 1):

The save method takes 2 arguments: model.save([attributes], [options]) - both optional.

Right now you are passing the options hash instead of the attributes. Try:

```
t.save(t.attributes, {
    success: function () {
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function (m, e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

or

```
t.save({'premium':true}, {
    success: function () {
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function (m, e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `me.fetch` sends GET request. There is nothing in Backbone that would issue GET request on save unless you have overridden the default sync method.

Save does only POST or PUT requests (POST if model doesn't have id and PUT otherwise).

Comment: I didn't override Backbonejs's sync method by the way.

Comment: You may try to add error callback to the fetch call to ensure that this is not fetch doing GET request that returns server error. Also you seem to save your model with `error` and `success` as model attributes, fix the save call as said in answer by Andrei Rosca.

Comment: I did exactly as Andrei was describing, it somehow worked in the development server but i still have the same issue in the production one (on Heroku)...